# Kick Out Form builder module

Tags: 7, forms, webforms

I have install [Form Builder](https://www.drupal.org/project/form_builder) module and [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module.

**Webform module:** Create form feature

**Form Builder:** Integrate into webform for more friendly user by click and drag

Recently I realize form builder is a annoying module.
Here are the problem cause by form builder:

> **1) Problem:** Unable to multiple select list.
>
> **Solution**: Webform module has a checkbox for multiple select. Just
>   check will do. Unfortunately, does not appear in form builder.
>
> **2)** Install Webform Hints module(Placeholder feature): Does not appear
>   in form builder.

As you can see without form builder, I realize all this features can be done by webform itself.

Now I uninstall form builder and face another stupid problem cause by form builder. Form component link is not working. Cant edit form unless I install back form builder module. 
See the picture below. I super regret to install such a useless module.

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: It will help if you shorten your question to the direct problem. You've just mentioned 2 different modules with completely different purposes, form builder & webform, plus side modules for webform: webform hints and maybe webform link? Are you saying webform link component links aren't showing up on your webform?

Comment: @ShawnConn I had edited the content. Kindly take a look.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I think you misunderstand what form builder is for. As it's project page says ...

> ... [it] does not provide any permanent mechanism for saving data with the created forms. In other words, it does nothing but build the form....

It's a utility for building form data structures, not for creating and capturing data for forms.

The module you're looking for, as you've found, is [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform). It provides an interface (albeit not as nice looking) to build web form content and capture data. That's the only module you need. It looks like from your image you've created a webform node. The form components tab link should present a form that allows you to add/edit components. As shown below...

[image]

If this interface isn't appearing I would make sure to uninstall both form builder & webform, remove form builder completely, make sure there is no node content type called **webform**, then try to reinstall webform again. It should work after a fresh install.